# Create json array using list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, pandas, dataframe

Suppose we have one data frame `df`

```
 id=['abc','xyz','lmn']
 df=pd.DataFrame(id)
 df.columns=['id']
 print(df)

     id
 0  abc
 1  xyz
 2  lmn
```

I want to generate the following array from it

```
 idd=[ { 'id': 'abc' ,},
       {'id': 'xyz',},
        {'id':'lmn' ,},]
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use method [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) with `records`:

```
In [61]: df
Out[61]:
    id
0  abc
1  xyz
2  lmn

In [62]: df.to_dict('records')
Out[62]: [{'id': 'abc'}, {'id': 'xyz'}, {'id': 'lmn'}]
```

**Edit**

It seems that docs lack information about keywords for `to_dict` method but you could get it from console:

> Help on method to_dict in module pandas.core.frame:
>
> **to_dict**(`orient='dict'`) method of pandas.core.frame.DataFrame instance
>       Convert DataFrame to dictionary.
>
> ```
> Parameters
> ----------
> orient : str {'dict', 'list', 'series', 'split', 'records', 'index'}
>     Determines the type of the values of the dictionary.
>
>     - dict (default) : dict like {column -> {index -> value}}
>     - list : dict like {column -> [values]}
>     - series : dict like {column -> Series(values)}
>     - split : dict like
>       {index -> [index], columns -> [columns], data -> [values]}
>     - records : list like
>       [{column -> value}, ... , {column -> value}]
>     - index : dict like {index -> {column -> value}}
>
>       .. versionadded:: 0.17.0
>
>     Abbreviations are allowed. `s` indicates `series` and `sp`
>     indicates `split`.
>
> Returns
> -------
> result : dict like {column -> {index -> value}}
> ```

Comment: If you need JSON, you can also use `df.to_json(orient = 'records')` or after importing the json library, `json.dumps(df.to_dict('records'))`. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html